# someone can help please? am getting an error saying expected } at the end of input

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

```
    //set initial values
int x = 0; // set initail zero value for the counter 
int preE = 512; // set initial value for light intensity in east direction 
int preW = 512; // set initial value for light intensity in west direction 
int predtime = 512; // set initial value for delay time 
int pretol= 512; // set initial value for tolerance value 
void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600); // set the baud rate for the serial monitor 

  // first set the relays off 
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); 
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH); // began the loop 
}

  void loop() 
  { 
    // Read the first reading 

    //read the east LDR 
    int E1 = analogRead(5); //read the west LDR 
    int W1 = analogRead(4); // read the delay time potentiometer 
    int dtime1 = analogRead(1);
    //read the tolerance potentiometer 
     int tol1 = analogRead(0); // Check if the readings reasonable, otherwise set them to previous ones. 

if (E1 < 10 || E1 > 1000 ) 
{ 
  E1 = preE ; 
  } 
  if (W1 < 10 || W1 > 1000 )
  { 
    W1 = preW ; 
    } 
    if (dtime1 < 10 || dtime1 > 1000 ) 
    { 
      dtime1 = predtime ; 
      } 
      if (tol1 < 10 || tol1 > 1000) 
      { 
        tol1 = pretol ; 
        }
        delay(100); // delay for one 0.1 second and take the next reading 

        int E2= analogRead(5); 
        int W2= analogRead(4); 
        int dtime2= analogRead(1); 
        int tol2= analogRead(0); 
        if (E2 < 10 || E2 > 1000 ) 
        {
          E2= preE ;
        }


if (W2 < 10 || W2 > 1000 )
{ 
  W2= preW ; 
  } 
  if (dtime2 < 10 || dtime2 > 1000 ) 
  {
    dtime2= predtime ; 
    }
    if (tol2 < 10 || tol2 > 1000 )
    {
      tol2= pretol ; 
      }
      delay(100); // delay for one 0.1 second and take the third reading 

      int E3= analogRead(5);
      int W3= analogRead(4); 
      int dtime3= analogRead(1); 
      int tol3= analogRead(0); 
      if (E3 < 10 || E3 > 1000 ) 
      {
        E3= preE ; 
        }
        if (W3 < 10 || W3 > 1000 )
        { 
          W3= preW ; 
          } 
          if (dtime3 < 10 || dtime3 > 1000 )

{
  dtime3= predtime ; 
  } 
  if (tol3 < 10 || tol3 > 1000 ) 
  {
    tol3= pretol ; 
    } 
    int E4 = analogRead(5);
    int W4 = analogRead(4);
    int dtime4= analogRead(1);
    int tol4= analogRead(0); 
    if (E4 < 10 || E4 > 1000 ) 
    {
      E4= preE ; 
      }
      if (W4 < 10 || W4 > 1000 )
      {
        W4= preW ; 
        }
        if (dtime4 < 10 || dtime4 > 1000 ) 
        { 
          dtime4= predtime ;
          }
          if (tol4 < 10 || tol4 > 1000 ) 
          {
            tol4= pretol ;
            }

delay(100); 
int E5 = analogRead(5); 
int W5 = analogRead(4);
int dtime5= analogRead(1); 
int tol5= analogRead(0);
if (E5 < 10 || E5 > 1000 ) 
{
  E5= preE ; 
  } 
  if (W5 < 10 || W5 > 1000 )
  { 
    W5= preW ;
    } 
    if (dtime5 < 10 || dtime5 > 1000 ) 
    { 
      dtime5= predtime ;
      } 
      if (tol5 < 10 || tol5 > 1000 )
      { 
        tol5= pretol ; 
      }
      delay(100); 
      int E6 = analogRead(5); 
      int W6 = analogRead(4); 
      int dtime6= analogRead(1); 
      int tol6= analogRead(0); if (E6 < 10 || E6 > 1000 )
      {
E6= preE ;
}
if (W6 < 10 || W6 > 1000 ) 
{
  W6= preW ; 
  }
  if (dtime6 < 10 || dtime6 > 1000 )
  {
    dtime6= predtime ; 
    } 
    if (tol6 < 10 || tol6 > 1000 ) 
    {
      tol6= pretol ; 
      } 
      delay(100); 
      int E7 = analogRead(5); 
      int W7 = analogRead(4); 
      int dtime7= analogRead(1); 
      int tol7= analogRead(0); 
      if (E7 < 10 || E7 > 1000 )
      {
        E7= preE ;
        }
        if (W7 < 10 || W7 > 1000 )
        { 
          W7= preW ; 
          }
          if (dtime7 < 10 || dtime7 > 1000 )

{ 
  dtime7= predtime ;
  }
  if (tol7 < 10 || tol7 > 1000 ) 
  { 
    tol7= pretol ; 
    }
    delay(100);
    int E8 = analogRead(5);
    int W8 = analogRead(4); 
    int dtime8= analogRead(1);
    int tol8= analogRead(0); 
    if (E8 < 10 || E8 > 1000 ) 
    {
      E8= preE ;
      } 
      if (W8 < 10 || W8 > 1000 ) 
      {
        W8= preW ; 
        } 
        if (dtime8 < 10 || dtime8 > 1000 )
        { 
          dtime8= predtime ;
          }
          if (tol8 < 10 || tol8 > 1000 )
          { 
            tol8= pretol ;
            }

delay(100); 
int E9 = analogRead(5); 
int W9 = analogRead(4); 
int dtime9= analogRead(1); 
int tol9= analogRead(0);

{
if (E9 < 10 || E9 > 1000 ) 
{
  E9= preE ;
  }
{
  if (W9 < 10 || W9 > 1000 )
  {
    W9= preW ; 
    } 
{
    if (dtime9 < 10 || dtime9 > 1000 )
    { 
      dtime9= predtime ; 
      }
{
      if (tol9 < 10 || tol9 > 1000 )
      {
        tol9= pretol ; 
        } 
        delay(100); 
        int E10 = analogRead(5);
        int W10 = analogRead(4); 
        int dtime10= analogRead(1);
        int tol10= analogRead(0); 

          if (E10 < 10 || E10 > 1000 ) 

        {
E10= preE ; 
} 
{
if (W10 < 10 || W10 > 1000 ) 
{
  W10= preW ;
  } 
  {
  if (dtime10 < 10 || dtime10 > 1000 ) 
  { 
    dtime10= predtime ;
    }
    {
    if (tol10 < 10 || tol10 > 1000 ) 
    { 
      tol10= pretol ; 
      } 

      //Average the ten readings 

   int E=(E1+E2+E3+E4+E5+E6+E7+E8+E9+E10)/10; 

   //light intensityin east
   int W =(W1+W2+W3+W4+W5+W6+W7+W8+W9+W10)/10; 

   // light intensity in west 
   int dtime=(dtime1+dtime2+dtime3+dtime4+dtime5+dtime6+dtime7+dtime8+dtime9+dtime10)/10; 

   int tol = (tol1+tol2+tol3+tol4+tol5+tol6+tol7+tol8+tol9+tol10)/10;// tolerance value 
   int delaytime = (dtime *10);// increase the delay by magnitude of 10 
   int tolerance = tol / 40; 

   // display the readings through serial monitor 
   Serial.println("Light intesity in the East"); 
   Serial.println(E); 
   Serial.println(" "); 
   Serial.println("Light intesity in the west"); 
   Serial.println(W);
   Serial.println(" ");
   Serial.println("delay time"); 
   Serial.println(delaytime); 
   Serial.println(" "); 
   Serial.println("tolerance"); 
   Serial.println(tolerance); 

   //check the differenc and open the coresponding relays 

   // check the diffirence of light intensity in east and west 
   int diff = E - W; 

   // check if the diffirence is in the tolerance else rotates the motor
   { 
   if (-1*tolerance > diff || diff > tolerance) 


   { 
    if (E > W)// check if light intensity in east is greater than in west 

    { 
      if ( x <30)// check counter to ensure the motor does not run infinitely 

    { 
      Serial.println("Turn motors towards east");

   digitalWrite(7, LOW);// Turn ON Relay 1 

   delay(2000);

   digitalWrite(7,HIGH); //Turn OFF Relay 1 
   ++x;
   }
   }
   //check if light intensity in west is greater than in east 
   else if (W > E) { if (x > -30)

   {
    }
    }
   }

Serial.println("Turn motor toward west");
digitalWrite(8, LOW);// Turn ON Relay 4 
digitalWrite(9, LOW); 
delay(2000); 
digitalWrite(8, HIGH);//Turn OFF Relay 4 
digitalWrite(9, HIGH); 
--x; 
// decrease counter 
}
}
}
//store the values for the next loop 

preE = 512; 
preW = 512; 
pretol= 512;
predtime = 512;
Serial.println(" "); 
Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------- ");
// delay the next loop 
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Copy your code into an editor which does proper indentation for C++ and the error should be obvious.

Comment: In the Arduino IDE press Ctrl+T for auto-indent. You have mismatch with '{' en '}'.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing five `}` at the end of your sketch.

As @Chris said, proper indentation will make your problem obvious. Use the menu Tools-AutoFormat (Ctrl-T) to format your sketch.

That's is looks like with the missing `}` added:

```
//store the values for the next loop

                        preE = 512;
                        preW = 512;
                        pretol= 512;
                        predtime = 512;
                        Serial.println(" ");
                        Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------- ");
// delay the next loop
                        delay(1000);
                    }    
//--- This } are missing in your sketch
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean no offence by this but you have got in such a mess because you have written monolithic code.  As a new developer you aren't expected to know this, I sure as hell didn't know it 30+ years ago.  The fact that you have posted you code on here, shows that it is too big for a normal brain to manage.  You loop function is over 300 lines long!  A screen full is about all a normal person can manage.

What I think you should do is refactor your code, look at it and pick out common blocks and turn them into functions, this will reduce the number of lines, making in it easier to read and reduce the possibility of bugs.  So firstly I notice you have this block repeated:

```
if (E1 < 10 || E1 > 1000)
{
    E1 = preE;
}
```

If you wrote that as a function:

```
int CheckLimits (const int& value, const int& lowerBound, const int& upperBound, const int& default)
{
  if (value < lowerBound || value > upperBound)
    return default;
  return value;
}
// This means those 4 lines collapse to this one line.
E1 = CheckLimits (E1, 10, 1000, preE);
```

Those 4 lines of code appear at least 39 times in loop, that's 120 lines that have just bee removed!

The `preE` value (and its pre friends) is never changed, so make it a constant and that will remove another 4 lines at the end.

Using literal numbers for your pins makes it harder to change them if you ever need to rewire.  More importantly it makes the code harder to understand, so always `#define` them at the top of you code.

If you create two variables to hold the same sort of number you should be thinking about using an array instead.  When you create E1 to E10  to hold ten readings, you should have done it in an array.  The array size should be a constant, defined in a single place, so you can change it if necessary.  And guess what, the averaging code should have been a function.

**ANYWAY**
I rewrote you code and hopefully it will explain what I mean.  Loop is down to about 90 lines now and it would be easy to make it smaller.  Yes, get a decent editor, Notepad++ or Visual Studio or Visual Code are all free, but you have to learn to think in smaller blocks, if you ever copy and paste more than one line, it probably should be a function :)

I haven't compiled it, but it should work - Please don't copy it just look at it and make your code better than this.

```
//set initial values
int x = 0; // set initial zero value for the counter 
static const int preE = 512; // set initial value for light intensity in east direction 
static const int preW = 512; // set initial value for light intensity in west direction 
static const int predtime = 512; // set initial value for delay time 
static const int pretol = 512; // set initial value for tolerance value 
// Define the PINS
#define APIN_E (5)
#define APIN_W (4)
#define APIN_DTIME (1)
#define APIN_TOL (0)
static const int MaxReadings(10);       // The number of readings used to form the average
int E_Reading[MaxReadings];             // Holds all the readings, not sure it is required any more, replaced by average variable.
int W_Reading[MaxReadings];
int dtime_Reading[MaxReadings];
int tol_Reading[MaxReadings];


void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // set the baud rate for the serial monitor 

                        // first set the relays off 
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH); // began the loop 
}

/// Check that the given value is within the limits
/// value: The reading to check
/// lowerBound : The lowest acceptable value
/// upperBound : The highest acceptable value
/// defValue : The value to use if outside the range.
int CheckLimits(const int& value, const int& lowerBound, const int& upperBound, const int& defValue)
{
    if (value < lowerBound || value > upperBound)
        return defValue;
    return value;
}

/// Take a reading from the specified pi and check it is within the acceptable bounds.
/// pinNumber   : The Analog pin number
/// lowerBound : The lowest acceptable value
/// upperBound : The highest acceptable value
/// defValue : The value to use if outside the range.
int TakeReading(const int& pinNumber, const int& lowerBound, const int& upperBound, const int& defValue)
{
    return CheckLimits(analogRead(pinNumber), lowerBound, upperBound, defValue);
}


void loop()
{
    int Eaverage = 0;
    int Waverage = 0;
    int dtimeaverage = 0;
    int tolaverage = 0;

    // Read the first reading 
    for (int index = 0; index < MaxReadings; ++index)
    {   // You don't actually need the values unless you want them, TakeReading could be assigned to the average variables.
        E_Reading[index] = TakeReading(APIN_E, 10, 1000, preE);         // read the east LDR 
        W_Reading[index] = TakeReading(APIN_W, 10, 1000, preW);         // read the west LDR 
        dtime_Reading[index] = TakeReading(APIN_DTIME, 10, 1000, predtme);  // read the delay time potentiometer 
        tol_Reading[index] = TakeReading(APIN_TOL, 10, 1000, prepretol);    // read the tolerance potentiometer 

        Eaverage += E_Reading[index];
        Waverage += W_Reading[index];
        dtimeaverage += dtime_Reading[index];
        tolaverage += tol_Reading[index];
        delay(100);
    }

    //Average the ten readings 
    Eaverage /= MaxReadings;
    Waverage /= MaxReadings;
    dtimeaverage /= MaxReadings;
    tolaverage /= MaxReadings;

    const int delaytime = (dtime * 10);// increase the delay by magnitude of 10 
    const int tolerance = tol / 40;

    // display the readings through serial monitor 
    Serial.println("Light intensity in the East");
    Serial.println(E);
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.println("Light intensity in the west");
    Serial.println(W);
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.println("delay time");
    Serial.println(delaytime);
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.println("tolerance");
    Serial.println(tolerance);

    //check the difference and open the corresponding relays 

    // check the difference of light intensity in east and west 
    const int diff = E - W;

    // check if the difference is in the tolerance else rotates the motor
    if (-1 * tolerance > diff || diff > tolerance)
    {
        if (E > W)// check if light intensity in east is greater than in west 
        {
            if (x < 30)// check counter to ensure the motor does not run infinitely 

            {
                Serial.println("Turn motors towards east");
                digitalWrite(7, LOW);// Turn ON Relay 1 
                delay(2000);
                digitalWrite(7, HIGH); //Turn OFF Relay 1 
                ++x;
            }
        }
        //check if light intensity in west is greater than in east 
        else if (W > E) 
        {
            if (x > -30)
            {
                // MISSING CODE??
            }
        }
    }
    Serial.println("Turn motor toward west");
    digitalWrite(8, LOW);// Turn ON Relay 4 
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);//Turn OFF Relay 4 
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    --x;
    // decrease counter 

    //store the values for the next loop 
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------- ");
    // delay the next loop 
    delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

usually unmatched brackets.

run your code through astyle and it will be more clear to you.